If $f(x) = f(x − a) + f(x − b) − f(x − a − b)$, is $f$ $\Bbb Q$-linear?
This question appeared in a test :
A map $f: V → W$ between finite dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb Q$ is a linear
transformation if and only if $f(x) = f(x − a) + f(x − b) − f(x − a − b)$, for all
$x, a, b ∈ V$. {True or False?}.
Here's my thought:
If $f$ is a linear transformation then the equation is clearly true but going the other way, if suppose the equation is true then putting $x=a+b$ in the equation we get :
$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)-f(0).$ But $f(0)=0$ hence it will be a linear transformation. The answer is True.
But in the answer key, it's given false. Where am I going wrong?

$f(x)\equiv w$ satisfies the hypothesis for any fixed $w \in W$ so $f$ need not be linear. How did you conclude that $f(0)=0$?

Moreover, even if $f(0)=0$, $f$ will indeed be $\Bbb Q$-linear but there remains some work to derive it from its additivity.

Oh I made a mistake when I assumed the equation is right then it wasn’t proved that f is linear so i can’t say f(0)=0. So does the problem have nothing to do with V and W being finite dimensional?

A function as described is necessarely $\mathbb{Q}-$affine, not linear. In fact, the solution is hidden in your argument: you proved that
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0),\qquad\forall x,y\in V.$$
In particular, an affine map can be written as
$$f(x)=L(x)+b=L(x)+f(0),$$
for $L\colon V\to V$ a linear transformation, and it is clear that
$$f(x+y)=L(x+y)+f(0)=L(x)+f(0)+L(y)\pm f(0)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0).$$
